# How can I access an object instantiated in the main method, from outside of the main method?

Tags: java

Here is my object in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
            String option = "-f";
            String filename = "src/greenhouse/examples4.txt";

            if ( !(option.equals("-f")) && !(option.equals("-d")) ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            printUsage();
            }

            GreenhouseControls gc = new GreenhouseControls();  

            if (option.equals("-f"))  {
            gc.addEvent(gc.new Restart(0,filename));
            }
            gc.run();

        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of parameters");
            printUsage();
        }  
      }
```

I'm creating a method that serializes the GreenhouseControls object and saves its state so that I can restore it later. It looks like this:

```
public void saveState() {
      try{
            // Serialize data object to a file
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("GreenhouseControls.ser"));
            out.writeObject(**gc**); // Can't do this from outside main method..
            out.close();

            // Serialize data object to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
            out.writeObject(**gc**); // Can't do this from outside main method...
            out.close();

            // Get the bytes of the serialized object
            byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
  }
```

I can't serialize from within main because I have to serialize it before a shutdown method occurs in the run() method that takes place in another class. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class Controller {
    private List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();

    public void addEvent(Event c) { 
        eventList.add(c); 
    }

    public abstract void shutdown();

    public void run() {
       while(eventList.size() > 0)

       for(Event e : new ArrayList<Event>(eventList))
          if(e.ready()) {
              System.out.println(e);
          try {
              e.action();
          }
          catch(ControllerException ex) {
              System.err.println("Reason: " + ex + "\n");
              saveState(); // There is where I want to invoke it..
              shutdown(); 
          }
          eventList.remove(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So, to reiterate, is there a way to gain access to the 'gc' GreenhouseControls object outside of main? I know I can create a new GreenhouseControls object inside the run() method but that would be a new instance without any of the data I need to save... right?

Comment: Your question appears incomplete -- what object needs to access the GreenhouseControls instance? You show only a snippet of "main method" code, and it only involves creating a GreenhouseControls object and nothing else. If this is your complete main method, then it appears that you're trying to get a reference to the GreenhouseControls from within itself, and if so, then `this` or `GreenhouseControls.this` should be adequate. If this is not the case, then please give us more information, enough so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: I added included some more code in my edit. Hopefully this clears it up a bit.

Comment: No, not for me. It still looks to me that all you need to do to get the gc instance is to call `this` or `GreenhouseControls.this`. Again, **where are you trying to get the instance**? In **what object**?

Comment: Well Peters solution works for me.

Comment: But it's not a good solution. You should not have to create static variables to solve this, and often this leads to trouble down the road, but if that's the solution you want, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in a class variable 
(also called field of the class). 
This is the right way.

So this should go to the class level (outside of all methods).

```
private static GreenhouseControls gc = null;
```

Then e.g. in the main method you just do:

```
gc = new GreenhouseControls();
```

And from there on any method of your class has access to gc.